# Error on web server=====>java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, servlets, nullpointerexception, jboss

I have created a simple servlet dynamic project with some html pages,....

As clicking the submit button on the form should transfer the control to servlet, I don't know what is the problem, it shows a "HTTP status 500" error....
It shows the error as:

Exception appears on the browser:
        java.lang.NullPointerException
    controller.Trafcontrol.doGet(Trafcontrol.java:48)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

App server used:JBOSS AS 4.2.2, Eclipse:Helios 3.6..

I need my control to be passed to servlet, so i can further process with my project.

I also include the "console" window content:

```
 `Servlet.service() for servlet servname threw exception
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at controller.Trafcontrol.doGet(Trafcontrol.java:48)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at
```

org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Please any one help on this, thx.....

Answer (score 1):

The error is very clear. You have a `NullPointerException` in your `Trafcontrol.java` at line 48. You have to check your own code, maybe using Eclipse debugging feature to step through your code.